# Update ListBox after Change SortDescription in CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, collectionviewsource

i've a ListBox in my Application, there have a CollectionViewSource as ItemsSource. In the CollectionViewSource is a SortDescription. There will works fine.

But now i have an Event there will Change the SortDescription. That works fine, but the ItemsSource will not refresh. When i try to update the ItemsSource with CollectionViewSource.View.Refresh() than i become an Error because CollectionViewSource.View is null.

Here is the Code that i used:

The CollectionViewSource:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=Vertraege}" x:Key="VertraegeSource">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Vertrag.Gruppe.ID" Direction="Ascending" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Grid.Resources>
```

The ListBox

```
<ListBox Name="lb_Vertraege" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource VertragsListBoxTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource VertraegeSource}}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
```

Has anywhere an Idea, what i can do to Update the ItemsSource after Modifying the SortDescription? At the Moment i try this with this C# Code:

```
ControlTemplate template = this["LeistungserbringerVertraegeTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
Grid grid = template.LoadContent() as Grid;

CollectionViewSource viewSource = grid.FindResource("VertraegeSource") as CollectionViewSource;

viewSource.SortDescriptions.Clear();
viewSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("VertragsID", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));

viewSource.View.Refresh();
```

Comment: By the Way, the ListBox and the Grid are in a ResourceDictionary with an CodeBehind-File.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, Template.LoadContent() is very unusual and not recommended in WPF.

A common way to retrieve the CollectionView is to get it from the ItemsControl that hosts the ItemsSource:

```
ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lb_Vertraege.ItemsSource);
```

then add your sort descriptions to the Filter delegate:

```
collectionView.Filter = ... // your sort descriptions
```

Comment: please note that CollectionViewSource is "a XAML proxy of the CollectionView class" (MSDN). The collectionView class itself represents a view. Going "I have a CollectionViewSource as ItemsSource" is the wrong way. If your ItemsSource is null, you have to initialize your data and set your ItemsSource. That does not affect the CollectionView at all. When you have a valid ItemsSource, you can change filter settings on the fly, and you won't need to set your ItemsSource null.